# Dynamic select boxes with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I tried to make dynamic select boxes(One boxes choosing info in another), but have some troubles.

#### routes.rb

```
get "students/new/update_tutors" => 'students#update_tutors', as: 'update_tutors'
```

#### students_controller.rb

```
def update_tutors
    admin = Administrators.find(params[:administrator_id])
    #@tutors = admin.tutors.map{|t| [t.info.name, t.id]}
    debugger
    @tutors = Tutor.where(administrator_id: params[:administrator_id])
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js
    end
end
def new
    @user = Student.new
    @is_super_adm = is_super?
    if @is_super_adm
      @tutors = Tutor.all.map { |t| [t.info.name, t.id] }
      @admins = Administrator.where(is_super: false).map { |adm| [adm.info.name, adm.id] }
    else
      @tutors = Tutor.where(administrator_id: session[:type_id]).map { |t| [t.info.name, t.id] }
    end
end
```

#### new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |student_form| %>
<!--....-->
<%= label_tag :administrator_id, "Choose local administrator" %><br/>
<%= select_tag :administrator_id, options_for_select(@admins), {id: 'administrator_selection'}  %><br/>
<!--....-->
<%= student_form.label :tutor_id, "Choose Tutor" %><br/>
<%= student_form.select :tutor_id, options_for_select(@tutors), {} , {id: 'tutor_selection'}%>
```

#### students.coffee

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#administrator_selection', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_tutors',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        administrator_id: $("#administrator_selection option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

#### update_tutors.coffee

```
$("#tutor_selection").empty()
    .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @tutors)) %>")
```

I tried to insert `alert('msg')` into `students.js.coffee`, and event worked, so I am sure that the problem is in `$.ajax` but this is first time I am working with ajax and I can't find the bug.

#### Update

I guess problem is in routing, but i didn't understand why it calls `students/update_tutor` instead `students/new/update_tutor`
*Log*
Started GET "/students/update_tutors?administrator_id=3&_=1459590346845" for  127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-02 11:47:01 +0200
Processing by StudentsController#show as JS
Parameters: {"administrator_id"=>"3", "_"=>"1459590346845", "id"=>"update_tutors"}

#### Fixed

I changed `update_tutors` in `$.ajax` to `'new/update_tutors'` and fixed error in update_tutors method in `Administrators.find(...)` to `Administrator.find(...)`.

Comment: removed `remote: true` from form, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Change your Ajax request as per given below,

$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#administrator_selection', (evt) ->
    $.ajax '<%= update_tutors_path %>',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        administrator_id: $("#administrator_selection option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```